# Meteor duplicate templates because of different content

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a menu bar and I have 3 different pages. Depending on which page I'm at, the contents inside the menu bar will differ. Since the contents are different, I've created 3 different templates. However, the structure of the menu bar is the same except for the contents so I find that I have a lot of duplicate code. Is there a way to have only one template and still populate the content inside the menu bar differently depending on which page you're on?

Setting the contents of template 1 (I do the same thing for the other two templates but only the name differs):

```
Template.pictureMenu.contents = function(){
  ...
};
```

Actual template (I do the same thing for the other two templates but only the name differs):

```
<template name="pictureMenu">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Media Menu</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Upload</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Playlists<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                **{{#each contents}} <!-- This is the only thing that changes-->
                  <li>
                      <a href="#" class="viewPlaylist">{{this}}</a>
                  </li>
              {{/each}}**
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Share</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form action class="navbar-search pull-right">
              <input class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

How would I reduce it to 1 template and still have different contents passed to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename your template to just "menu" and then insert specific content at the location where the content varies:

```
<template name="menu">
  ...
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {{#each currentMenu}}
      <li>{{itemName}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  ...
</template>

Template.menu.currentMenu = function() {
  return Session.get("currentMenu");
}
```

Then when you change locations in your site and you want to update the menu, just update the session:

```
var newMenu = [{itemName: "item1"}, {itemName: "item2"}, {itemName: "etc"}];
Session.set("currentMenu", newMenu);
```